# @Transactional annotation not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I am trying to save a `TestEntity` object in the database. The code is being executed and the Id for the entity is created, but the entity is not persisted to the database (no row inserted):

```
@Repository
public class DBConnectionConfig {
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    DBConnectionConfig(){
        //this.sessionFactory=getSessionFactory();
    }
    /*private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    private void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }*/
    public Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}


package com.homecare.persistance.repository;
@Repository
@Transactional
public class HomeCareDaoImp extends DBConnectionConfig  implements HomeCareDao{
    Logger LOGGER=Logger.getLogger("Connection.class");
    Session session=null;
    Transaction trnx=null;
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;
    @Autowired
    DBConnectionConfig dBConnectionConfig;
    public void doaProcess(TestEntity testEntity){
        LOGGER.info(dBConnectionConfig.toString());
        session=getSession();
        // trnx=session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(testEntity);
        // session.flush();
        // trnx.commit();
        LOGGER.info("connection established");
    }
}
```

Removing the comments from the 3 lines (beginTransation, flush, commit) solves the problem, but why does the `@Transactional` annotation not work here?

Spring XML:

```
<!-- Our service layer components -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.homecare" />
<!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.homecare.persistance.repository" /> -->


 <!-- enable @Transactional Annotation -->



<!-- data source with c3p0 -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/My_DB" />
      <property name="username" value="postgres" />
      <property name="password" value="password" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.homecare.persistance.resource"></property>   <!-- yet to defined place where to scan> -->
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

POM xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>



<!-- spring framwork -->
<!-- Hibernate -->
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
           <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.2.0</version>
       </dependency>
```

Comment: I don't see `<tx:annotation-driven/>` that enables transaction mgmt

Comment: it is there in spring xml file( third last tag):
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate session object used for save is not tied to transaction manager defined in spring config xml.

Define the sessionfactory object using autowired as

```
@Autowired
Private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

And fetch session object as

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

And now perform the session.save(object);

As per spring config in your code, sessionFactory is associated with transactionManager. So all the changes performed session (associated with transaction manager) will get committed in db when transaction completes successfully.

Comment: I am injecting SessionFactory object using Autowired annotation only.and Transactional annotation will also work with openSession() then why do you want me to use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
I also updated the code the way i am injecting SessionFactory object.

Comment: SessionFactory.openSession() always opens a new session that you have to close once you are done with the operations. SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() returns a session bound to a context - you don't need to close this.

Comment: Yeah that is fine. but my issue is different. My actual question is why spring transactional annotation feature is not working?

Comment: Did you try testing transaction commit by changing to  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()?.  If still not working, you can add <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>.

Comment: Thanks Vijay. it is working fine with sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() and  without using <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop> tag. but it lead some doubt to me.
First one is :
why it is not working for sessionFactory.openSession()?
Second one is:
To make sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() work we are suppose to add <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> in spring xml file. But here i have not added it but still working.

Can you help me out with that?

Comment: When new transaction started, HibernateTransactionManager creates  new session object (using sessionFactory reference). This session object can fetched using sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() and when transaction ends, session object values are committed in db and session closed. If we start using session.openSession(), then it creates new session but this session is not bound to existing transaction session context. Here, session.beginTransaction() is required and that transaction need to managed explicitly.

Comment: Property hibernate.current_session_context_class helps to define the session context scope whether it is JTA, thread, Custom. But not mandatory to have it unless there is a requirement to handle explicitly.

Comment: it sounds good. Thanks to clear my doubt make me understand new thing.  One last question Can we use @transaction on sessionFactory.openSession() or not?

Comment: When we use sessionFactory.openSession(), @transaction is not mandatory as session.beginTransaction() handles the transaction. But boundary is limited to beginTransaction() and transaction.commit().

Comment: Make sure you accept this answer if it has solved your issue, that rewards the person who answered and also helps people identify faster the fix that was necessary

Answer (score 0):

Try by overriding the getSession() method:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class HomeCareDaoImp extends DBConnectionConfig  implements HomeCareDao{
    Logger LOGGER=Logger.getLogger("Connection.class");
    Session session=null;
    Transaction trnx=null;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    public void doaProcess(TestEntity testEntity){
            LOGGER.info(dBConnectionConfig.toString());
            session=getSession();
            // trnx=session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(testEntity);
            // session.flush();
            // trnx.commit();
            LOGGER.info("connection established");
        }

    @Override
    public void getSession() {
        super.getSession();
    }   
  }
```

Comment: After making the above changes, Still entity is not committing to the db.